# How to properly configure ROOT_URLCONF

Tags: python, django, web, frameworks, django-urls

I'm going through django tutorial and I have an issue with ROOT_URLCONF line in settings.py.
  If it's set to 'mysite.urls' index page isn't being found. If I set it to 'polls.urls' it's working but admin page isn't found now.

What's the issue?

Here's my file hierarchy:

[image]

[image]

**--UPDATE--**

...mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

...polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Please show the actual `urls.py` files.

Comment: It should certainly be mysite.urls; the problem lies in the content of those files, but as knbk says we can't help until you show them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1):

You should have `ROOT_URLCONF = mysite.urls`. Since you have included the polls app under `r'^polls/'`, you can access the polls index view at

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/
```

If you want to create a url pattern for `http://localhost:8000/`, then add it to your url patterns in `mysite.urls`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i resolved it using following change:

In the setting.py, you should have
    `ROOT_URLCONF=mysite.urls`

But inside mysite/urls.py,
    `import polls.urls`
it will then locate the index page.